# Insert variable string into formula

Tags: vba, excel

Been working on this for a while, and can't seem to figure it out. I feel like I'm almost there, thanks to different posts in here. Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a dependent list that I would like to change to it's first value based on the selection of the first list. I found a code here, that I modified to work for my sheet, but I had to change all the names in the first list to conform to the Define Name rules(ie. no spaces). This works, and I can leave it at that, but I would prefer to have the spaces in my list. Whenever I use the formulas I was using to change the name shown in the list, the VBA script no longer works. I feel that it is because it is not seeing a change in the target cell, although the value is changing, the formula in the cell is not. Is that an accurate statement? If so, what can I change to make it work the way I want it to? Right now, the dependent list is running off `=INDIRECT("$B$5)` but I would like it to run off `=INDIRECT('Store Data'!$A$23)` which contains a `VLOOKUP` formula.

Here is the VBA script I am using now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng(1) As Range, rng1 As Range
Set rng(0) = Range("B5") 'your primary selection
Set rng(1) = Range("G5") 'your secondary selection range
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, rng(0)) Is Nothing Then 'if you have changed your primary selection
    For Each rng1 In rng(1) 'each cell in your secondary selection
        i = i + 1
        rng1 = Worksheets("SD Names").Range("" & rng(0).Value2)(i, 1) 'gets changed to the nth value in the indirect reference of the primary selection ("TeamA" 's second row is "MemberA2" for example)
    Next
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Hope this is enough detail, thank you for any help!

Comment: A *change* caused by *evaluation* of a static formula doesn't trigger the `Worksheet_Change` event, but it does trigger the `Worksheet_Calculate` event (provided `EnableEvents = True`).

Comment: If you'd prefer spaces in your list values then use spaces but replace them with (eg) underscores for your defined names and perform the translation in the WorkSheet_Change handler.  For Example for "Team A" the matching range name is "Team_A" `rng1 = Worksheets("SD Names").Range(Replace(rng(0).Value2, " ", "_"))(i, 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the help! While on lunch, I was thinking about it while away from my laptop, and was able to see the answer that I just got to work. I found code on here to see when there is a change in a certain cell, then moved that cell's value to another cell, and pointed everything to that cell. Might be a round about way to get it done, but it works. Thanks again for the quick replys!